# nginx location regex not matching for wp-login.php or wp-admin.php only but everything else

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I want to only allow login to wordpress to all users but me, so in my nginx configuration file I added:

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login) {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    allow (my hidden IP);
    deny all;
}
```

so, I noticed that all of the URLs that end with "/wp-admin" or "/wp-login" match the rule and hence they are not allowed except for /wp-admin.php and /wp-login.php. Does anyone know why?

Thank you

Comment: Regular expression locations are evaluated in order until a matching rule is found. If your `location ~ \.php$` block is placed above this one, it will intercept any URI which ends with `.php`.

Comment: @RichardSmith you are exactly right, I do have a location \.php$ block before that one, mhhh but I noticed I need to do the lines of code that are inside of that block location ~ \.php$ which are more important than the block I pasted in my OP, are there any alternatives or options?